# Maven failsafe plugin fails with "Unable to locate surefire-booter"

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

Our Maven build is suddenly failing in Jenkins as of August 2nd. We cannot explain why maven failsafe cannot access it's dependent "booter" plugin.

Has anyone seen the same thing?

```
[INFO] [failsafe:integration-test {execution: run-integration-tests}]
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Foo/integration-tests/target/failsafe-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to locate surefire-booter in the list of plugin artifacts
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate surefire-booter in the list of plugin artifacts
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.getForkConfiguration(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1152)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:655)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:647)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Comment: Crossing this thread over.

<b>Solution:<b>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585784/troubles-with-surefire-plugin-the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properl/19842636#19842636

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is confined to Maven Failsafe 2.12.1 which [a directory listing from the Apache repo](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) shows was released late on August 1st.

The workaround is to fix your version in your POM to the earier 2.12 or you might also want to try later versions such as 2.12.2 or 2.12.3 (which post date this answer).  I have not tried these later versions and "2.12" is the version string that worked for me.

Just add chosen version where the plugin is declared in the POM.

Presumably this works because only 2.12.1 has the problem (which is undiagnosed, AFAICT)

Comment: i'm having this same issue with version 2.20.1. Downgrading to 2.20 fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem using Maven 2.  Switching to Maven 3 resolved my issue.  Also Simon's answer of incrementing the maven-surefire-plugin worked with Maven 2.