# Jenkins build failed with error "The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

```
15:54:14 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project <name>: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
15:54:14 [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /workspace/<projectname> && /opt/jdk/oraclejdk-1.8.0.60/jre/bin/java -jar /workspace/<projectname>/target/surefire/surefirebooter701256924917362962.jar /workspace/<projectname>/target/surefire/surefire1124075194275791830tmp /workspace/projectname/target/surefire/surefire_29076614812591057339tm
15:54:14 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
15:54:14 [ERROR]
```

This is a Jenkins CI job, using Java 8 and Maven 3.3. All the unit test are successful. Still getting this error, tried lot of solution mentioned, but not working. tried everything mentioned in the below link, but no help

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html

Comment: This question has already been answered: [23260057](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260057/) and [12585784](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585784/). E.g. use `-e` to get a full stack trace of the error. If that doesn't give enough infos, use `-X` for debugging infos. Etc.